# Is this transmission fluid high enough?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid

2013 Corolla...  This was after my car was driving for 45 minutes on the highway. I checked with the car running in park. This is with wipeing the stick with a clean cloth before inserting to check.

Is this transmission level high enough? It's hard to tell since the fluid is clear in many spots

[image]

[image]

Comment: The level *appears* to be between the two notches which indicate **HOT**. If so, plenty of fluid as long as the measurement was obtained correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is hard to tell from the photos you included but looks like you are ok. by that i mean you appear to have enough fluid in the trans to keep it safe and operate ok (slipping or hard shifting). you can usually see the fluid better on the dipstick in a shaded area, you can angle to dipstick to a light source and look for a reflection. the fluid is more reflective than the metal dipstick.